# iOS Slide Out Menu

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I currently have a view controller that handles a facebook login as well as a landing page after the authentification named "homeViewController". What I would like is a nice slide out menu and layout to be presented on the "homeViewController". I found one I really like, but find the instructions on how to implement rather hard to follow being a beginner. I have downloaded the source, and when running the source in xcode, everything is wonderful, so I know it works. I find the instructions confusing because it tells me to include "REFrostedViewController.h" which I did, then it tells me to perform the following, but I don't have "DEMONavigationController:

```
DEMONavigationController *navigationController = [[DEMONavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[DEMOHomeViewController alloc] init]];
DEMOMenuViewController *menuController = [[DEMOMenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

// Create frosted view controller
//
REFrostedViewController *frostedViewController = [[REFrostedViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController menuViewController:menuController];
frostedViewController.direction = REFrostedViewControllerDirectionLeft;

// Make it a root controller
//
self.window.rootViewController = frostedViewController;
```

Is there an easier way to get this menu working on my "homeViewController.m"? Any help would be appreciated.

Instructions for slide out menu: https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController

Comment: Leave Xcode alone. Xcode is just an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "`DEMO`" files you're referring to are found [in the "Examples" folder](https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController/tree/master/Examples/Simple/REFrostedViewControllerExample) in that GitHub Repo.

For your own use, you will need to take those demo files and modify them for your use and then drop them into your own project.

As for your "`homeViewController.m`" file, I would imagine you'd replace the first line of that code with something like:

```
DEMONavigationController *navigationController = [[DEMONavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[homeViewController alloc] init]];
```

(by the way... you should name your Objective-C classes and files with capital letters.  It's methods, properties and variable names that should start with lower case letters).